# How to update mesh data via blender python script?

Tags: python, blender

I can create a mesh in blender with this script:

```
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mymesh")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("myobj", mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
mesh.from_pydata([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]], [], [[0, 1, 2]])
```

However, if I try to update the mesh data with `from_pydata` again, it results in an error:

```
RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
```

Is there a way to update the mesh data after the mesh has been created?
(I'm trying to avoid deleting the object and creating it again with new data.)

Answer (score 1):

Facing this problem, it seems there can be a couple of causes.

- incorrect formatting or number of verts / faces (eg 2D or 4D vertex)
- trying to modify an existing mesh

To replace the context of an existing mesh, clearing the existing mesh data works to make from_pydata work again

```
import bmesh

# reset mesh by copying an empty one
nm = bmesh.new()
nm.to_mesh(obj.data)
nm.free()

obj.data.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `from_pydata` function takes lists of data and creates a [mesh data block](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html). Once you have the mesh data block you can adjust the mesh properties directly. These can be found in the [`vertices`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshVertex.html), [`edges`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshEdge.html) and [`polygons`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html) properties of the mesh data.

```
obj.data.vertices[0].co.x = 1.25
```

Mostly this data should not be directly altered, any changes made while in edit mode will get overwritten as the edit mesh is stored as bmesh data. The [bmesh module](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) provides faster access and methods to alter mesh data and can also update the mesh while in edit mode.